# How to receive multicast packets hitting NIC without actually sending IGMP request?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I have 2 Ubuntu 16.04 machines "A" and "B" in my local network. "A" periodically sends multicast UDP packet targeted at 225.0.0.37.

On system "B" I can verify through wireshark that those packets are hitting my NIC. I want to write a C program which creates a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket and listens to these packets without sending IGMP join packet in the network. If I write such a program the kernel doesn't allow these packets to reach my application. They get filtered on IP layer 3 (its my guess).

Is there a way of achieving this? I don't want any IGMP packet leaving my system but still want to capture the UDP traffic. One option that I know works is to use `SOCK_RAW`, but i want to achieve this from `SOCK_DGRAM` only.

I know that os keeps igmp subscription entries in `/proc/net/igmp` and `/proc/net/dev_mcast`. And these entries are created only if I send an `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` request from an interface from a program. And these entries get cleared as soon as the program terminates. Maybe there is a way to fool kernel to create this entry.

Comment: "_periodically sends multicast UDP packet targeted at 225.0.0.37._" You should not be using a RESERVED multicast address. You should probably use something in the Administratively Scoped range of `239.0.0.0/8`. Also, not using IGMP with a switch that does IGMP snooping will not work because the switch will never send the multicast frames to your destination host. If you are routing multicast, the router will not send to your network without IGMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things:

1. just switch your interface into promiscuous mode like this: `ip link set en123 promisc on`, or
2. continue to set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` but add a netfilter rule to drop the resulting IGMP packet from actually leaving you host.

---

Usually, it shouldn't be an issue that IGMP packets are leaving your system.

Thus, I'm curious why you have this special requirement.